# Recording audio using safari (Macos) seems to have Cut Off at around 12 KHz

Tags: audio, safari, web-audio-api

I am working on Web Audio API. I tried recording an audio file using Web Audio API saved the recorded chunk and later plotted the spectrum of same chunk using python matplotlib.

**The playing audio file contain increasing frequency from 2KHz to 20KHz.**

The audio recording from chrome seems to be proper and i am able to see it properly with audio spectrum.

[image: Audio File Recorded from Chrome]

*but when recording audio from safari there seems to be a cut off filter after 12 Khz.*

[image: Audio File Recorded From Safari]

**Web Audio Code function start_rec() is called on a button click**

```
var samplerate = 48000;
var audio_engine_var = {};


var samples = {
    audio_samples: [],
    samplerate: samplerate
}

function start_rec() {
    audio_engine_var.context = new AudioContext({sampleRate:samplerate});
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
        { audio: {
            echoCancellation: false,
            sampleRate: 48000
        } }
    ).then( function (stream) {
        audio_engine_var.stream = stream;
        audio_engine_var.track = audio_engine_var.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        audio_engine_var.track.applyConstraints(
            {
                echoCancellation: false,
                sampleRate: 48000
            }
        );
        audio_engine_var.scriptProcessor = audio_engine_var.context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);
        audio_engine_var.scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
            let aquired_samples = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            aquired_samples.forEach(element => {
                samples.audio_samples.push(element);
            });
        }
        audio_engine_var.input = audio_engine_var.context.createMediaStreamSource(audio_engine_var.stream);
        audio_engine_var.scriptProcessor.connect(audio_engine_var.context.destination)
        audio_engine_var.input.connect(audio_engine_var.scriptProcessor);

        setTimeout(function() {
            download_samples();
        }, 15 * 1000) // stop recording and download audio samples.
    });
}


function download_samples(){
    // stop audio engine
    audio_engine_var.context.close();    
    audio_engine_var.scriptProcessor.disconnect() ;

    // download_audio
    var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(samples));
    var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href",     dataStr);
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", "audio.json");
    document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox
    downloadAnchorNode.click();
    downloadAnchorNode.remove();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 200 ) // stop recording and download audio samples.
}
```